# Chkdsk taking almost two days

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, chkdsk, filesystem-corruption, sdhc

I used `chkdsk /r` on my 32GB SDHC card but it has already taken almost two days.

While I was listening to music, which was in the sd card, on my smartphone, suddenly it told me the sd card is corrupted and need to format the card. I used my laptop opening the SDHC card, it can read the directories but cannot access it. So I try "check disk" on the card.

After I typed `chkdsk D: /r` , the next line showed the type of the file system is FAT32 and something like "chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another process", I typed `Y` to dismount the volume then it showed the serial number. Nothing has shown after this line.
I found that people always say about stage 1 to stage 5 or the percentage completed while chkdsk is running, but my console didn't show any of these or any progress.

What should I do now? Let it run for few more days or stop the process? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any valuable data on the SD card which you don't have backed up? If not, format it and reload the music. However, this sounds like the card could be going bad, so you might want to talk to the card's manufacturer.

Comment: Can I safely stop the chkdsk process or it won't be a matter if I'm gonna format it.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Kill it. The card is probably _fscked_ anyway.